# Deleted contacts are showing up in the recipients list for New Email

Tags: email

Wanting to check in here before creating a Issue at GitLab...

I've discovered when creating a New Email (not a Mailing), deleted contacts are available as Recipients. They are not available in the CC or BCC fields. This is different, but perhaps related to this SE Question: [Mailing to contacts in a group - deleted contacts were included to the list of recipients](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/37931/mailing-to-contacts-in-a-group-deleted-contacts-were-included-to-the-list-of-r).

Sounds like a bug, right? It's certainly not the behavior I expected.

CiviCRM 39.5.0, Joomla 3.10.6

Comment: I'd file an issue. It's like that on the latest version too and is (probably) wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed a bug. Issue created on [GitLab](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3098)